# Calculating Normalized Device Co-ordinates

Tags: java, matrix, opengl-es

So I wanted to find the NDC co-ordinates of the red vertex of this triangle after it has been transformed. I'm using it as a prototype to work out how to add and position health bars in a game I am developing (is there a different method?).

The co-ordinates are not being calculated correctly (they are somewhat close to being correct and follow a similar path but they are not correct). I can't figure out why.

```
float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];
float[] modelViewMatrix = new float[16];
float[] modelViewProjectionMatrix = new float[16];

// Position/rotate the triangle and draw it.
Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, -0.3f, 0.3f, 0.0f);
multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);
glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

// The vertex data defined for the red vertex
float[] redVertex = { triangleVertexData[0], triangleVertexData[1],
            triangleVertexData[2], 1.0f };
float[] ndcCoordinates = new float[4];
multiplyMV(ndcCoordinates, 0, modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, redVertex, 0);
```

The triangle vertex data is defined as (removed the colour data for this post for simplification):

```
final float[] triangleVertexData = {
    -0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f, // Red vertex
    0.5f, -0.25f, 0.0f,  // Blue vertex
    0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f     // Green vertex
};
```

The 'ndcCoodinates' are not quite right. Any suggestions?[image: The application]

Comment: What API do you use to access OpenGL?  LWJGL?  JOGL?

Comment: Sorry I don't know, I'm using OpenGLES and Android studio which handles it for you.

Comment: Solution: divide the ndcCoordinates XYZ values by the W value